# Drupal7 Webforms - Stripe implementation

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, stripe-payments, drupal-webform

I have to implement a Stripe payment with Drupal Webforms. I've tracked down and installed the required modules as listed bellow.

1. https://www.drupal.org/project/payment
2. https://www.drupal.org/project/stripe
3. https://www.drupal.org/project/payment_webform

I already have a webform defined for what i need, however i don't know how to add the payment at the end of the form.

I tested out the stripe payment in admin and it works.

Flow:

Fill the forms, go to personal details (name, email, etc), go to payment processing.
The payment ammount is build dynamicly depending on the user's choices (multiple choice, build a service package sort of thing).
Hope it's enough information.

I am unable to implement a working sollution for what is required of me. Did anyone else had to do something similar? maybe you could give me some pointers.

Comment: Please ask a question and provide an example of what you have tried to solve the issue

Comment: Edited: added a question. I can't give all the example, i tried numerous implementations of existing modules. I even tried to implement drupal commerce just for the payment, and then call the purchase hooks from my module.